# What is the time complexity of this code block?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I calculate the time complexity?

```
While(n>0)
      For j in n
          Count+=1
      n = n/2
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `j in n`?

Comment: I think it is a loop from 0 to n.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried/found out so far? Share your findings/ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O(n).

n+ n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n = O(n)

Comment: Are you sure? There are two nested loops.

Comment: @BulutOztemur Why do you think that it would be something else? This answer could use some more words to explain it, but it does already show how it arrives at its conclusion.

Comment: @BulutOztemur As a sanity check, you can implement the code snippet in a language of your choice and print `count`. It should be close to `2*n`.

Comment: I thought inner loop complexity is n. And the outer has logn because of n=n/2. So, i thought result is nlogn. But as you Said, when i print count, it is close to 2*n. So, the result is n?

Comment: Yes, it is `O(n)`.